# Proof using the ratio test

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Searching for some help with proving that the ratio test is inconclusive for any series that has the form $\sum \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}$ where both $p$ and $q$ are both polynomial functions.

I know that for the ratio test you must adhere to the following criteria,

1) $lim _{n->\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = L < 1$ then the series is convergent.

2) $lim _{n->\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = L > 1$ or $ L = \infty$

3) $lim _{n->\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = L = 1$ then no conclusion can be made.

So how do I show that $\sum \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}$ where both $p$ and $q$ are both polynomial functions has a $lim=1$

Comment: If you plug in the definition of $a_n$, you obtain that you need to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert\frac{q(n+1)p(n)}{p(n+1)q(n)}\right\rvert=1$$ Now: two polynomials (why is this the case?) $f,g$ have $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ if and only if...

Comment: the highest power of f and g have the same coefficient?

Comment: And something else.

Comment: not sure what that other thing may be

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x+2}{3x^9+76}=?$.

Comment: Show that $p(n+1)/p(n)\to 1$ if $p$ is not constantly $0$, and that $q(n)/q(n+1)=[(q(n+1)/q(n)]^{-1}\to 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the degree of $p(n)$ is greater than the degree of $q(n)$ then the term ratio will itself diverge (and so the series must diverge).

If the degree of $p(n)$ is less than the degree of $q(n)$ then the term ratio will go to $L = 0$ (and so the series must converge.

If degree of $p(n)$ is equal to the degree of $q(n)$ then here is how to show that the term ratio approaches $1$ as $n\to\infty$ (so that the naive ratio test is inconclusive):

Let $p(n) = \sum_{k=0}^d p_k n^k$ and  $q(n) = \sum_{k=0}^d q_k n^k$; note that the degree $d$ is the same in both cases.

Let $s = \max_k |p_k|$ and let  $t = \max_k |q_k|$. Then using 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} n^k = \frac{n^d-1}{n-1}
$$
we see that
$$ |p_d| n^d  - s\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \leq |p(n)| \leq |p_d| n^d  + s\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \\
|q_d| n^d  - t\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \leq |p(n)| \leq |q_d| n^d  + t\frac{n^d-1}{n-1}
$$
and the term ratio $r_n = \frac{p(n+1)q(n)}{p(n)q(n+1)}$ obeys
$$
\frac{\left( |p_d| (n+1)^d  - s\frac{(n+1)^d-1}{n}\right)\left(|q_d| n^d  - t\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \right)}{\left( |q_d| (n+1)^d  + t\frac{(n+1)^d-1}{n}\right)\left(|p_d| n^d  + s\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \right)} \leq r_n \leq 
\frac{\left( |p_d| (n+1)^d  + s\frac{(n+1)^d-1}{n}\right)\left(|q_d| n^d  + t\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \right)}{\left( |q_d| (n+1)^d  - t\frac{(n+1)^d-1}{n}\right)\left(|p_d| n^d  - s\frac{n^d-1}{n-1} \right)}
$$
The left hand expression is always $\leq 1$ and the right hand expression is always $\geq 1$. I will show that the limit, as $n\to\infty$, of the left hand expression is $1$; the proof that the right hand expression goes to $1$ is similar, and once you know that these bounding expressions go to $1$, you have $\lim r_n = 1$.

Divide both numerator and denominator by $n^d(n+1)^d$ yielding
$$
X_n=\frac{\left( |p_d|  - s\frac{(n+1)^d-1}{n(n+1)^d}\right)\left(|q_d|  - t\frac{n^d-1}{(n-1)n^d} \right)}{\left( |q_d|  + t\frac{(n+1)^d-1}{n(n+1)^d}\right)\left(|p_d|  + s\frac{n^d-1}{(n-1)n^d} \right)} =
\frac{\left( |p_d|  - \frac{s}{n}\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^d}\right]\right)\left(|q_d|  - \frac{t}{n-1}\left[1-\frac{1}{n^d} \right]\right)}{\left( |q_d|  + \frac{t}{n}\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^d}\right]\right)\left(|p_d|  + \frac{s}{n-1}\left[1-\frac{1}{n^d} \right]\right)} $$
$$
X_n = 1- \left( \frac{s}{n|p_d|}+  \frac{t}{(n-1)|q_d|} + \frac{s}{(n-1)|p_d|}
+\frac{t}{n|q_d|}  \right) + O(n^{-2})
$$So by choosing $n$ large enough we can make that expression arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try and learn this now